# How can I use queue like `yield queue.get()` in tornado ,between some Process?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, queue, tornado

I am coding a project.

I try to make it like below:

- start two process by python `multiprocessing`,one of which is a tornado project,need asynchronous.
- the two process like a task-sender and a task-worker.

So I use the Queue try to be the queue between two process,also,it would be work,but should like below

```
data = queue_a.get()
```

which is not asynchronous,I want to do like below(which I did not found a way to realize):

```
data = yield queue_a.get()
```

Now,I do like below to make it more asynchronous,but not good enough:

```
while True:
    if queue_a.empty():
       yield
    else:
       data = queue_a.get()
raise gen.Return(data)
```

Could someone toll me how to make it asynchronous? Thanks very much

Comment: May someone else,also care about the question. Can new a thread,to use `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`, to use  the thread switching,not run the while all the time.(Sorry for  my poor English).

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical producer-consumer problem with an unbounded buffer. A pattern as follows should suffice.

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def _task_sender(queue):
    print('task_sender started')
    for data in range(1, 5):
        print('task_sender created data {}'.format(data))
        queue.put(data)
    queue.put(None)
    print('task_sender finished')

def _task_worker(queue):
    print('task_worker started')
    while True:
        data = queue.get()
        if not data:
            break
        print('task_sender got data {}'.format(data))
    print('task_worker finished')


pool = mp.Pool(2)
manager = mp.Manager()
queue = manager.Queue()

task_sender = pool.apply_async(_task_sender, (queue,))
task_worker = pool.apply_async(_task_worker, (queue,))

task_sender.get()
task_worker.get()
```

### Sample output

Note that output ordering is non-deterministic due to the nature of concurrency.

```
task_sender started
task_sender created data 1
task_worker started
task_sender created data 2
task_sender created data 3
task_sender created data 4
task_sender got data 1
task_sender finished
task_sender got data 2
task_sender got data 3
task_sender got data 4
task_worker finished
```

### Additional info

- `.get()` may throw an exception
- It is important that `.get()` is not chained -- if you do that, `task_worker` will not start until `task_sender` finishes
- If your data has zeros or Nones, define some other sentinel value
- You can use objects rather than functions -- there are two ways:

  - Implement `__init__`
  - Implement `__call__`
- The logging module is recommended, and should be configured to display some sort of identifier for each thread

  - See https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

Comment: certainly it can slove a typical producer-consumer problem.but for some reason,for example, I must use the tornado to keep some connect ,which should use the async. So, any other answer?